# Jquery Datatable: Added data does not match known number of columns

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to fix an issue with this code that triggers a warning as a js alert when the viewed is rendered and datatable is empty. I've never used this plugin so I don't really understand how it works pretty much... So, basically in the view-side is the following code:

```
var dataTable;
$(function () {
dataTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("Attendance", "Reports")",
        "aoColumnDefs": [
        {"bSortable":false,"aTargets":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]},
        {"bSearchable":false,"aTargets":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]}
        ],
        "fnServerData":function(sSource, aoData,fnCallback){   
            var from= $('#DateSelect').val();
            var until= $('#DateSelect2').val();                
            aoData.push({"name":"From","value":from},{"name":"Until","value":until});                
            $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {               
                fnCallback(json)
            });
        }           
    }).fnSetFilteringDelay(300);        
 });
```

Below on the code there's an input button that triggers dataTable.fnDraw() when clicked and it works fine. So, basically, the only problem here is when rendering the view for the first time since dataTable is empty and the warning is displayed.

Here is a sample of the jSon response from the Controller to the View when the table is empty (causing the warning to display):

```
 {"iTotalRecords":0,"iTotalDisplayRecords":0,"sEcho":1,"aaData":[[]]}
```

And this is a json after querying for some results working good:

```
 {"iTotalRecords":17,"iTotalDisplayRecords":17,"sEcho":2,"aaData":[["Venue 1","<div align=center>30</div>","<div align=center>4</div>","<div align=center>13</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>3</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>7</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>3</div>","<div align=center>14</div>"],["Venue 2","<div align=center>41</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>5</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>1</div>"],["Venue 3","<div align=center>20</div>","<div align=center>3</div>","<div align=center>15</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>5</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>8</div>","<div align=center>4</div>","<div align=center>4</div>","<div align=center>11</div>"],["Venue 4","<div align=center>46</div>","<div align=center>5</div>","<div align=center>10</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>5</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>20</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>7</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>15</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>28</div>"],["Venue 5","<div align=center>18</div>","<div align=center>9</div>","<div align=center>50</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>10</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>3</div>","<div align=center>21</div>"],["Venue 6","<div align=center>10</div>","<div align=center>4</div>","<div align=center>40</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>18</div>","<div align=center>3</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>4</div>","<div align=center>22</div>"],["Venue 7","<div align=center>44</div>","<div align=center>3</div>","<div align=center>6</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>7</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>4</div>"],["Venue 8","<div align=center>8</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>12</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>6</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>7</div>"],["Venue 9","<div align=center>23</div>","<div align=center>7</div>","<div align=center>30</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>8</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>15</div>"],["Venue 10","<div align=center>22</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>4</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>4</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>7</div>"],["Venue 11","<div align=center>10</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>20</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>5</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>10</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>5</div>","<div align=center>17</div>"],["Venue 12","<div align=center>17</div>","<div align=center>3</div>","<div align=center>17</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>4</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>7</div>"],["Venue 13","<div align=center>23</div>","<div align=center>10</div>","<div align=center>43</div>","<div align=center>4</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>13</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>5</div>","<div align=center>23</div>"],["Venue 14","<div align=center>21</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>9</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>15</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>17</div>"],["Venue 15","<div align=center>6</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>8</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>6</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>1</div>","<div align=center>14</div>"],["Venue 16","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>2</div>"],["Venue 17","<div align=center>25</div>","<div align=center>6</div>","<div align=center>24</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>2</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>0</div>","<div align=center>7</div>","<div align=center>3</div>","<div align=center>3</div>","<div align=center>13</div>"],["<b>TOTAL Venezuela</b>","<div align=center><b>364</b></div>","<div align=center><b>61</b></div>","<div align=center><b>16</b></div>","<div align=center><b>11</b></div>","<div align=center><b>35</b></div>","<div align=center><b>1</b></div>","<div align=center><b>2</b></div>","<div align=center><b>0</b></div>","<div align=center><b>47</b></div>","<div align=center><b>8</b></div>","<div align=center><b>114</b></div>","<div align=center><b>16</b></div>","<div align=center><b>35</b></div>","<div align=center><b>223</b></div>"]]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send back;

```
{"iTotalRecords":0,"iTotalDisplayRecords":0,"sEcho":1,"aaData":[]}
```

otherwise it is interpreted not as an empty array, but an array with one element wich is an empty array

Answer (score 1):

try sending back `"aaData":[]` instead of `"aaData":[[]]` (remove the inner brackets)